# access to id in sub-page

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I want to test my web page with Selenium WebDriver. My web page contains two subpages as shown in the code below:

globalPage.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="tabs">
            <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">tab1</label> 
            <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
            <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">tab2</label>     
            <div class="clear-shadow"></div>            

            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-1">                       
                    <object id="formM" type="text/html" data="page1.html" width="848" height="720"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="content-2">
                    <object id="commT" type="text/html" data="page2.html" width="960" height="630"></object>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>      
</body>
```

The page1.html contains an element whose id is "myId1".

page1.html

```
...
...
<div class="preview">
    <fieldset id="myId1">
        <form name="page">
            <label for="cb" id="labelPop">pop:</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb" checked="checked" onclick="valid();showPop();" /><br />            
            <label for="ta" id="labelMessage2">Message:</label> 
                <textarea disabled="true" id="ta" name="ta" cols="22" rows="9"></textarea>          
            <label id="labelFile2" >file:</label>
            <input type="file" name="validate" id="upload2" disabled="disabled"/>                                               
        </form>     
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="myId2">                   
        <label id="labelPrio">Prio:</label>
            <select id="selectPrio">
                <option value="one">High</option>
                <option value="two">Low</option>
            </select><p></p>
        <label id="labelMessage1">Message:</label>
            <textarea  id="areaa" cols="17" rows="8"></textarea><p></p>                                                             
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <label id="labelFile1">file:</label>
            <input id="upload1" type="file" name="file[]" >
        </form>                             
    </fieldset> 
</div>
...
...
```

my code Selenium is:

```
....
....
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        this.baseUrl = properties.getProperty("base.url", "http://monIp:8080/TestPage");
    }

    @Test
    public void firefoxTest() throws Exception {
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        testSelenium();
    }

    private void testSelenium() throws Exception {
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        this.driver.get(this.baseUrl + "faces/globalPage.html");

        new Select(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id='myId1']/select[3]")))
    }
    ....
    ....
```

i have a error: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//fieldset[@id='myId1']/select[3]"}`
how can i resolve this problem ?

when i try

```
this.driver.get(this.driver.get(this.baseUrl + "faces/page1.html");
```

it works great but i dont have my tabs.

so my question is: how can i access to "id" in the subpage?

Thanks for help!

Comment: It would help if you also provided the html for your page1 as that is the page that you want our help with.

Comment: I added the html of page1 in my post above. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the html for gobalPage.html, you don't have a <fieldset> element which is most likely why you're receiving the exception. You do have such an element on page1.html though. As such, I'm still a little lost on what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: That is yes.
I want to switch to a fieldset of my page "page1.html" through my page "globalPgae.html"
my global page is as below
Two tabs, the Content of Tab 1 is coded with page1.html
and the Content of Tab 2 is coded with page2.html

in my selenium code I want to access to the id of page1.html Through my globalPage.html

Comment: Right, now I understand. Ok, here's something to try: `page1 = driver.findElement(By.id("formM")); page1.findElement(By.id("myId1"));`

Comment: thank you for help, but i have the same error :Unable to locate element : {"method";"id",selector";"myId1"}

Comment: I've had a play about with a couple of local files copy-pasted from the above. I've never come across a situation where a page is displayed within a page like you have here - and it appears that Webdriver really can't handle it as far as I can tell.